# Convert ast node into python object

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

Given an `ast` node that can be evaluated by itself, but is not literal enough for `ast.literal_eval` e.g. a list comprehension

```
src = '[i**2 for i in range(10)]'
a = ast.parse(src)
```

Now `a.body[0]` is an `ast.Expr` and `a.body[0].value` an `ast.ListComp`. I would like to obtain the list that `eval(src)` would result, but given only the `ast.Expr` node.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for [`compile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#compile)? The result of calling `compile()` on an AST object is a code object that can be passed to `eval()`.

---

```
>>> src = '[i**2 for i in range(10)]'
>>> b = ast.parse(src, mode='eval')
>>> eval(compile(b, '', 'eval'))
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

Comment: I tried but did not seem to get it working. E.g. `compile(a.body[0],'','eval')` gave the error `expected Expression node, got Expr`. (Is `Expr` not just short for `Expression`?)

Comment: No - `Expr` is what is contained in the body of an `Expression`. Try just passing `a` instead of `a.body[0]`. (From [the grammar](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#abstract-grammar).)

Comment: Try using `ast.parse(src, mode='eval')` to get an `Expression` object.

Comment: about your edit: if I change the mode to 'eval' I get problems other-where in my code