# How do you compile an ast.Expr?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

```
import ast

code = '1+1'
expr = ast.parse(code).body[0]
print(type(expr))
compile(ast.Expression(expr), 'string', "eval")
```

gets me

```
class '_ast.Expr'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_ast.py", line 6, in <module>
    compile(ast.Expression(expr), '<string>', "eval")
TypeError: expected some sort of expr, but got <_ast.Expr object at> 0x7fe89442d9e8>
```

```
compile(expr, '<string>', "eval")
```

does not works either:

```
TypeError: expected Expression node, got Expr
```

Answer (score 4):

TLDR: replace `expr` by `ast.Expression(expr.value)`

A comment on this [Convert ast node into python object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747873/convert-ast-node-into-python-object) and [makeMonday's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52820217/4518341) gave me the solution:

```
import ast

code = 'a+1'
expr = ast.parse(code).body[0]
print(eval(compile(ast.Expression(expr.value), '<string>', "eval"), {"a": 4}, {}))
```

Answer (score 1):

An interesting explanation about Expressions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32429203/1660507).

But basically, the answer's first paragraph says it all:

> `Expr` is not the node for an expression per se but rather an expression-statement --- that is, a statement consisting of only an expression. This is not totally obvious because the abstract grammar uses three different identifiers `Expr`, `Expression`, and `expr`, all meaning slightly different things.

So, in your case, you would need to dump the Expr first:

```
>>> ast.dump(expr)
'Expr(value=BinOp(left=Num(n=1), op=Add(), right=Num(n=1)))'
>>> compile(ast.dump(expr), 'string', "eval")
<code object <module> at 0x1065d2ae0, file "string", line 1>
```